# Customizer freezes on Ubuntu 11.10 using 32 bit or 64 bit iso

Tags: 11.10, iso, customizer

I downloaded Customizer 3.2.1 from `ppa:customizer-dev-team/devel` and ran the application through the terminal so I could see the output. I have tried both 32 bit and 64 bit isos, but once the isos are selected the file browser closes but all the buttons stay grayed out. I have tried both 32 bit and 64 bit ISOs of Ubuntu 11.10 from the Ubuntu website. They have been tested for integrity. Here is the terminal output up to the time the program crashed:

```
williamt@FatalError-HP-Ubuntu:~$ gksudo /home/williamt/1/GUI.gambas
===================== Get_Str() begin =====================

[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf`
[DEBUG] SrchStr: WORK_DIR=
[DEBUG] Def: /home
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf

================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================


===================== Get_Str() begin =====================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: WORK_DIR=
[DEBUG] Def: /home
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================


===================== Get_Str() begin =====================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: WORK_DIR=
[DEBUG] Def: /home
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================

[EVENT] Checking configuration file
[EVENT] Checking essential directories and files
[EVENT] Disabling widgets

===================== Get_Str() begin =====================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: ISO=
[DEBUG] Def: 
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================


=================== Replace_Str() begin ===================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: ISO=
[DEBUG] RpcStr: /home/williamt/Downloads/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64 (1).iso
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] Saving file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================ Replace_Str() end (found) ================

[DEBUG] Extracting ISO
[EVENT] Detecting Terminal Emulator
[EVENT] Checking essential directories and files
[EVENT] Disabling widgets
```

This is really puzzling to me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to file a bug report. That's on Launchpad.net. This site isn't suitable for it.

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for how to file a bug, which a crash most certainly is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use /opt/Customizer/CLI.sh (use "-h" argument to see the help) to
extract the ISO. See the documentation for more details how to use
Customizer from the CLI (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PfhHnSBjv-
IDI7Yh5obhMGYCAV9Gw1NPEynU4GqKTsA/edit) but keep in mind the the
argument to extract the ISO is now "-e" or "--extact" and the path to
the ISO must be specified in /opt/Customizer/settings.conf before doing
so and must be quoted (i.e. ISO="/home/user/test.iso").

If the terminal outputs error that a variable is not set in
settings.conf when extracting than probably the GUI is doing something
wrong .

Please, do the following so I can see whether the variables are set
correctly:

1. run Customizer
2. click "Select ISO" and choose the ISO you want
3. cat /opt/Customizer/settings and post the output

Also, make sure that you update Customizer (if the PPA doesn't contain
recent build you can update with the install.sh script, just follow the
instructions at https://github.com/fluxer/Customizer/wiki/Install) to
the last stable version available. The master (stable) branch is not
frozen and if I find critical bugs/issues I fix them in it too so
tracking on the GitHub.com page for commits is recommended (altought the
PPA should be up to date in matter of few hours, worst case scenario in
a day).

-- You received this bug notification because you are subscribed to the bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/920975 
Title: Customizer 3.2.1 Fails to load ISO in Ubuntu 11.10 
Status in Customizer - LiveCD Remastering Tool: New Bug description: 
I have tried loading both 32 bit and 64 bit ISOs from the Ubuntu website of Ubuntu 11.10. None seem to work. I am using Customizer 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. I installed the application from the ppa ppa:customizer-dev-team/devel and from the zip file provided on github. Both have the same problem. The bug is as follows: When I open the program, all buttons are grayed out except "Select ISO". When I click the button and navigate to the Ubuntu 11.10 ISO I want to remaster, I click open and the file browser dialog closes. The interface has not changed, all the buttons are still grayed out except "Select ISO". I can do this as many times as I like, the same thing happens. The terminal output is as follows:

```
williamt@FatalError-HP-Ubuntu:~$ gksudo /home/williamt/1/GUI.gambas
===================== Get_Str() begin =====================

[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf`
[DEBUG] SrchStr: WORK_DIR=
[DEBUG] Def: /home
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf

================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================


===================== Get_Str() begin =====================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: WORK_DIR=
[DEBUG] Def: /home
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================


===================== Get_Str() begin =====================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: WORK_DIR=
[DEBUG] Def: /home
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================

[EVENT] Checking configuration file
[EVENT] Checking essential directories and files
[EVENT] Disabling widgets

===================== Get_Str() begin =====================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: ISO=
[DEBUG] Def: 
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================== Get_Str() end (found) ==================


=================== Replace_Str() begin ===================
[DEBUG] SrchFile: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] SrchStr: ISO=
[DEBUG] RpcStr: /home/williamt/Downloads/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64 (1).iso
[DEBUG] Loading file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
[DEBUG] Saving file: /opt/Customizer/settings.conf
================ Replace_Str() end (found) ================

[DEBUG] Extracting ISO
[EVENT] Detecting Terminal Emulator
[EVENT] Checking essential directories and files
[EVENT] Disabling widgets
```